# Generating equal-distance band regards to one boundary of polygon in R?

Tags: r, polygon, rgeos, buffer

I have a polygon that is made up of several points:

[image]

Basically, this reflects the contour of a tumor tissue.
Now I have another polygon, which is defined as 'front', means a region where tumor and normal tissue in contact with tumor (the gray region):
[image]
Now what I want to do is generate multiple lines, whose distance towards the inner boundary of the 'front' is linearly increased with a factor of 0.15, as the figure shows:

[image]

I tried to use function 'gBuffer' from package 'rgeos', however, it seems like doing buffer for a single line does not make any sense. I also tried doing gBuffer for the entire polygon, however, I want to remain the lower boundary, which means gBuffer for entire polygon is not doable...

Quite confused about what to do, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! When you say 'by a factor of 0.15', do you mean as a percentage of the total height of the diagram? Or a fixed distance?

Comment: What does your code so far look like?

Comment: @Simbamangu The width for each band is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Please click 'edit' and add the code you've tried so far, so that your question can be re-opened!